# Язык C, объявление структур внутри структур

Tags: c, struct

Рассмотрим ситуацию:

```
struct a
{
    int id;

    struct b
    {
        int x, y, z;
    };

    struct b obj;
};

struct b B;// Так должно быть нельзя...
```

Что говорит **Стандарт** в этой ситуации?

Можно ли в области видимости, где находится определение **struct a**, объявлять переменную типа **struct b**?

По логике, со структурой, описанной внутри описания другой структуры, все должно быть точно так же, как с переменными и функциями, - такое вложенное объявление должно иметь локальную область видимости.

Но **MinGW** так делать позволяет. Может, это неопределенное поведение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Язык С запрещает объявлять одну структуру внутри другой без одновременного объявления поля этого типа. Ваш код ошибочен.

Вот так можно

```
struct a
{
    int id;

    struct b
    {
        int x, y, z;
    } obj;
};

struct b B; // OK
```

При этом "внутренний" структурный тип `struct b` все равно объявляется в охватывающей области видимости. В С нет такой "локальной" области видимости, как "структура".

---

К слову:

В дополнение к объявлению новых типов внутри структур, язык С (в отличие от С++) позволяет также объявлять новые типы внутри операторов приведения типа и внутри оператора `sizeof`. Объявленные таким образом типы будут видны снаружи, в охватывающей области видимости

```
size_t n = sizeof(struct b { int x, y, z; });
struct b x; // OK
```

и

```
void *p = (struct b { int x, y, z; } *) 0;
struct b x; // OK
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А  относительно объявления функций? Функции, объявленные внутри других функций, видны за пределами области своего объявления?

Comment: Максим: В смысле? Каком образом вы собрались прикрутить сюда объявление функции?

Comment: Сюда - никаким. Но обычно удобно внутри функции объявить вспомогательные функции, чтобы их использовать, но при этом не засорять область видимости выше.

Comment: @Максим: В стандартном С такого нет.

Comment: Стандартный C - это C89? Меня интересуют современные диалекты - C99 и C11

Comment: @Максим: Нет, стандартный С - это именно С11. Но такого не было никогда, нив С89/90, ни в С99. "Диалектами" обычно называют нестандартные/расширенные ответвления С. В диалектах GNU поддерживаются вложенные функции.

Comment: Странно, я много где такое встречал. По крайней мере в GNU GCC - точно.

Comment: @Максим: О том и речь. Это развеселое студенческое творчество GNU-шников. К стандартному С не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.